# Devise custom routes slippery slope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, devise

I started using custom routes w/Devise so that I could have my 'Sign In' and 'Sign Up' routes go to the same page. However, as soon as I followed the instruction from Devise about custom routes, it seems that *every* route now has to be explicitly specified. This has now broken my reset password links since that portion is handled by Devise.

What am I doing wrong here? You can see below that I've had to spell out everything for my User and UserSessions model. Shouldn't I only have to specify the ones I want to change?

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "user_sessions" ,:registrations=>"users"},:skip => [:sessions] do

 get 'users/sign_in' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
 get 'users/sign_up' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
 post 'users/sign_in' => 'user_sessions#create', :as => :user_session
 post 'user_sessions' => 'user_sessions#create', :as => :app_sign_in
 delete 'users/sign_out' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
 get 'users/sign_out' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
 post 'users/:id' => 'users#update', :as =>:update_user
 get 'users' => 'users#index'
 get 'users/:id/edit' => 'users#edit', :as => :edit_user
 get 'users/:id' => 'users#show', :as => :show_user
 delete 'users/:id' => 'users#destroy', :as => :destroy_user

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use, not sure if this will work for you

```
   devise_for :users
   devise_for :users do
     get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
   end
```